# Will using recursive generator cost less memory?

Tags: python, performance, function, loops, tuples

I have pools of tuples like [(0,0,27,4) (36,0,16,5) (14,36,14,8)], [......

I would generate tuples of tuple from the pools of tuple with the following rule, summing up the each index must not exceed or equal the limit more than 1 times.

tuple has length of 4, every its objects are int.
Let's say I have an limit tuple (30,29,28,27), and pools of tuples.
For example, selecting tuples from pools, one from each pool,

```
pool = [[(5,5,8,9),...],[(10,5,16,3),....],[(12,5,8,15),.....]]
selected =((5,5,8,9), (10,5,16,3), (12,5,8,15))

summing up each index,
5+10<30, 15+12<30 exceeding(or same as) limit 30 for 0 time ok
5+5<29, 10+5<29 exceeding limit 29 for 0 time ok
8+16<28, 24+8>28 exceeding limit 28 for 1 time ok (<2times)
9+3<12, 12+15=27 same as limit27 for 1 time ok
```

so ((5,5,8,9), (10,5,16,3), (12,5,8,15)) will be yielded.

but example of ((5,5,18,9), (10,5,10,3), (12,5,8,13)),

```
5+10<30, 15+12<30 exceeding(or same as) limit 30 for 0 time ok
5+5<29, 10+5<29 exceeding limit 29 for 0 time ok
18+10=28, 18+8 >28 exceeding limit 28 for 2 time False
9+3<12, 12+13<27 exceeding limit27 for 0 time ok
```

will not be yielded.
If I use itertools.product, I need additional loop for generating tuples. But If I try to modify the given the code roughly equals to 'itertools.product',

```
def product(*args):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args]
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

and making the 'result' in last line costs all the time, because I'm making 6 tuples with its each length is 80.

so I've generated recursive generator,

```
def underlimit_product(*args, limit = (30,30,30,30), ncount = (0,0,0,0), exceed = 2, start = (0,0,0,0)):
    # (5,0,0,0),(0,5,0,0),(0,0,5,0),(0,0,0,5)
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args]
    if max(ncount) >= exceed:
        raise StopIteration
    if not pools:
        raise StopIteration
    if len(pools) == 1:
        for y in pools[0]:
            if any([a+b>=c and d for a,b,c,d in zip(y,start,limit,ncount)]):
                if ncount:
                    continue
                else:
                    yield (y,)
            else:
                yield (y,)
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        for x in pools[0]:
            for y in pools[1]:
                count = [e+1 if b+c>=d else e for b,c,d,e in zip(x,start,limit,ncount)]
                if any(count):
                    n = underlimit_product(*pools[1:], ncount = count, exceed = exceed,limit = limit, start = [a+b for a,b in zip(x,start)])
                    for results in n:
                        yield (x,*results)
                else:
                    n = underlimit_product(*pools[1:], ncount = count, exceed = exceed,limit = limit, start = [a+b for a,b in zip(x,start)])
                    for results in n:
                        yield (x,*results)
    raise StopIteration
```

## test

```
pool = [[(5,5,8,9),(5,5,18,9)],[(10,5,16,3),(10,5,10,3)],[(12,5,8,15),(12,5,8,13)]]
b= list(underlimit_product(*pool, limit = (30,29,28,27)))
((5,5,8,9), (10,5,16,3), (12,5,8,15)) in b
True
((5,5,18,9), (10,5,10,3), (12,5,8,13)) in b
False
len(b)
16
```

So I'm seeing better product...maybe... , will it loosen my computer's memory?
Will it be much faster than using itertools.product and check all the values?

Comment: “Will it be faster?” - use timeit and you’ll find out. “will it loosen my computer’s memory?” I’m not sure what this question means.

Comment: @barny making result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool], it costs 80**6 lists for 6 pools with 80 lengths. but using recursive generator would cost for saving its variables, I'm not sure what would be work in smaller memory.

Comment: So you’re working in Python and worried about memory usage. Hmm.

Comment: @barny well my task manager showed its usage is 3GB